# Is it a data race to access shared data after joining a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Does the following code result in a data race:

```
int f()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::thread t{[&]{ i = 1; }};
    t.join();
    return i;
}
```

No mutex or atomics are used for `i` access.

[Documentation of std::thread::join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) talks about "completion of the thread synchronizing with the corresponding successful return from join()", but I'm not sure would it be relevant in this context.

Comment: After the join, there is only a single thread - how could there be a race?

Comment: There is no promise that the update of the variable is visible.  In practice this always works because the low-level implementation of join() cannot work without a memory barrier.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes the visibility of the update was my concern here. I was wondering is the cppreference.com quote in the question somehow related to that. Brian's answer below suggests that it would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the linked page says,

> The completion of the thread identified by *this synchronizes with the corresponding successful return from join().

This implies that anything that happens in `t` before `t` exits (that is, anything that happens in `t`) happens before anything that happens in the main thread after `t.join()` returns. Therefore, the write to `i` within thread `t` happens before `i` is read by the return statement. Therefore, the two accesses to `i` are not potentially concurrent. Therefore, there is no data race.

Comment: Found the relevant standard quote: "An evaluation A strongly happens before an evaluation B if either: A is sequenced before B, or *A synchronizes with B*..." [intro.races]

Answer (score 5):

> Does the following code result in a data race

No.  The rule is if you have more than one thread, and at least one of them is a writer, you need synchronization when accessing shared data.  The key point here is *more than one thread*.  After you call `join`, you no longer have more than one thread so `main`'s access of `i` is safe.