# Filling std::vector by different threads

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I need fill one std::vector on differents threads.

Is it correct code? Or I should to add mutex for my code?

```
void func(int i, std::vector<float>& vec)
{
    vec[i] = i;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vec(6);
    std::list<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(func, i, std::ref(vec)));
    }
    for (auto iter = threads.begin(); iter != threads.end(); iter++)
    {
      (*iter).join();
    }
}
```

I tested my code it works fine. Are there any pitfalls? Is it thread safe code?

What about get std::vector data by different threads?

Comment: Why do you multiply `i` by 4? You are reading your vector out of bounds starting with the third thread.

Comment: i*4 is misprint

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Related question:
[Is std::vector thread-safe and concurrent by default? Why or why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131743/is-stdvector-thread-safe-and-concurrent-by-default-why-or-why-not).

It's thread-safe because you're not modifying the vector size, and not attempting to write to the same memory location in different threads.

To future proof this answer for anyone who doesn't drill down into the link:

1. It's not thread safe *only* because they're using the `[]` operator. It's thread safe because each thread is explicitly modifying a *different* location in memory.
2. If all threads were only reading the same location using `[]`, that would be thread safe.
3. If all threads were writing to the same same location, using `[]` won't stop them from messing with each other.
4. I think if this were production code, at LEAST a comment describing why this is thread safe would be called for. Not sure of any compile time way to prevent someone from shooting themselves in the foot if they modify this function.

---

On point #4, we want to communicate to future users of this code that:

1. No we're not guarding this standard library container even though that should be your gut reaction, and
2. Yes we've analyzed it and it's safe.

The easy way is to stick a comment in there, but there's a saying:

> The compiler doesn't read comments and neither do I.
> -Bjarne Stroustrup

I think some kind of `[[attributes]]` should be the way to do this? Although the [built-ins](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) don't seem to support any kind of thread safety checking.

---

Clang appears to provide [Thread Safety Analysis](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html):

> The analysis is still under active development, but it is mature enough to be deployed in an industrial setting.

Assuming you implement other functions that would require a `std::mutex` to be responsible for your `std::vector`:

```
std::mutex _mu;
std::vector<int> _vec GUARDED_BY(_mu);
```

then you can explicitly add the `NO_THREAD_SAFETY_ANALYSIS` attribute to turn off the safety checking for this one specific function. I think it's best to combine this with a comment:

```
// I know this doesn't look safe but it is as long as
// the caller always launches it with different values of `i`
void foo(int i, std::vector<int>& vec) NO_THREAD_SAFETY_ANALYSIS;
```

The use of `GUARDED_BY` tells me, in the future, that you are thinking about thread safety. The use of `NO_THREAD_SAFETY_ANALYSIS` shows me that you have determined this function is okay to use - especially when other functions that modify your `vector` are not marked `NO_THREAD_SAFETY_ANALYSIS`.

**2024 Edit**

This question doesn't ask about accessing the data after calling `std::thread::join` on the threads. Which you would obviously do in a normal program. It is not a data race to read the data after joining the threads. See [Is it a data race to access shared data after joining a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55224600/2027196).

The calls to `join()` guarantees that all accesses in the threads happens before any accesses after the `join()` calls.

Comment: Interesting answer (and question). My instinct would have been that even the `op[]` were not guaranteed safe (even though in practice there's little reason for it to fail). Nice!

Comment: what do you mean "out of bounds." is it i pass argument i * 4?

Comment: @dzukp Yes. You have 6 slots but you try to write up to slot 24. You may have intended something like `vec[i/4] = i;`?

Comment: Ah, that's better then.

Comment: Good shout on the comment, as well. Far too many don't bother with this.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings can we think of another way to ensure some compile-time warning or error against different threads writing to the same location? I cannot. Comments drift over time. Better than nothing though. Not sure if there's some suite of implementation-defined `[[attributes]]`?

Comment: A bit more formally on the use of `operator []` here: if two or more threads access the same location and at least one of those those threads writes to it, you have a data race, which means you have undefined behavior. That's essentially the wording from the standard, and it's a more dense way of saying what the points numbered 1-3 in the answer say. +1.

Comment: fwiw, passing `begin` and `end` iterators instead of the whole container decreases the risk of mistakes, also it makes the range for each thread more explicit

Comment: @JohnFilleau I think that's largely intractible with current technology. There's a reason it's almost never auto-diagnosed

Comment: misread the question. I thought every thread fills a range of values, if it is just a single element then pass only a single iterator. Then each thread can only do something obviously wrong but not something that is hard to spot

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's thread safe because you are neither writing to the vector object itself from different threads nor writing to the same object in the vector underlying array .

when you construct the vector you allocate space for 6 elements and fill them with zero for pod types like `int`. These elements are placed in an array owned and managed by the vector and the vector exposes them via iterators and `operator []`.

So when you edit an element in the vector you don't edit the vector itself so you don't have to protect the vector with a mutex.

You will need a mutex if you are modifying the vector itself or the same element in different threads .